# How to show accumulated cpu usage of top 10 processes?

Tags: cpu-usage

I know the command `top`, but `top` only shows the actual numbers for cpu and memory usage. But sometimes many numbers fluctuate very quickly, so it's hard to find out which processes really need much of cpu time.

Is there a way to display the accumulated cpu time during the last 15 Minutes or last 2 hours? Maybe along with maximum memory usage.

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly what you are looking for but the following command

```
 top -o TIME+
```

will get the top sorted by accumulated CPU time since the process started.

Answer (score 0):

It's not quite what you were looking for but the `htop` command will show you the amount of CPU time each process has used since the last reboot.

Comment: Do you mean [`htop` columns](https://linux.die.net/man/1/htop) TIME, STIME, UTIME or other?